# Is there an equivalent of Java's AssertionError in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, testing

I'm trying to write some test helpers for a gem, and would like to provide some assertions that will trigger test failures where appropriate.

In Java, this is achievable (if I recall) by throwing an `AssertionError`, which should then get picked up by the test runner and Just Work. Does anything like this exist for Ruby?

For example, let's say I have a gem `emily-post`, which provides some helpful methods for checking how polite a request is:

```
request = 'I can haz cheezburger?'
EmilyPost.is_polite?(request) # false

request = 'I can haz cheezburger, please?'
EmilyPost.is_polite?(request) # true
```

Let's say as part of this gem I want to provide test helpers that can:

- Set up an (im)polite request
- Verify that the response is also polite

For example my test might read like:

```
include EmilyPost::TestHelpers

with_polite_request do
    response = 'No way!'
    issue(response) # This rude response should fail the test
end
```

The code for `with_polite_request` might look something like:

```
def with_polite_request
    request = 'I can haz cheezburger, please?'
    yield
    raise AssertionError unless is_polite?(response)
end
```

...where `AssertionError` would preferably be some error recognised by any test framework as a failure, rather than an error.

Does any such error exist?

Comment: Raising any error will cause a test to fail, unless the test explicitly expected that error. But to answer your question - no, there is no generic error, different test libraries use different ways. If you are using rspec, check out how you can define your own [custom matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher).

Comment: This generally isn't the way testing is done with ruby. There are no errors you can raise in your app code that will only be recognized by tests. There are two major Ruby testing frameworks you should take a look at, [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) and [test-unit](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit). RSpec is more widely supported.